# Error installing numpy using pip to Python 2.7.9 in cmd prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, cmd

I have used pip install to install modules like six, pytz, setuptools, python-dateutil, and pyparsing, but I get an error when typing the following into the cmd prompt to install numpy:

```
pip install numpy
```

I have already used the following commands in the command prompt in Windows 8.1:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python34\libs
```

(I did these to install the modules listed before.)

Now for numpy specifically, I've tried downloading numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl from the following site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

. . . and then putting the .whl file into C:\Python27\libs, then typing the following into cmd:

```
pip install wheel
```

That worked. But when I type this:

```
pip install numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl
```

I get the following error:

```
Requirement 'numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the
 file does not exist
```

Why can't pip install numpy from the .whl file in the libs folder?

EDIT: Malik Brahimi's solution worked. I opened from the current directory and re-added the folder with the pip file, then installed the numpy file. I'd upvote the solution if I knew how.

Comment: You need to open command prompt in the current directory.

Comment: Navigate to the folder with the wheel and follow along [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjuNpLkLe0U) with the same command.